# How to connect Java to Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

I got these errors for my Java program. I have already put the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar` inside my classpath. How to solve this?

```
HSystemRDB.java:144: package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist
    Driver driver = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
                                      ^
HTestClassRDB.java:99: package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
```

The code:

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://wire:3306/h?user="+pSystemRDB.USERNAME+"&password="+pSystemRDB.PASSWORD;
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    String query1 = "Delete from dbase";
    String query2 = "Delete from id";


    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception:");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Well, it's probably not lying. Are you sure the mysql connector is in your classpath? Have you read this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html#connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager

Comment: He could try `String s = "java" + "mysql";`  ... :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to download the mysql package from: [here](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.14.zip/from/http://mysql.mirror.easycolocate.nl/) and place it inside the library, i'll edit the excact steps in a few min

this is the correct syntax to connect to a database:

```
try
{
  // create a java mysql database connection
  String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
  String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
  Class.forName(myDriver);
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");

  // your prepstatements goes here...

  conn.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: useful and understandable!!

Answer (score 7):

You need to add [MySQL Driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) in your classpath for that , and import appropriate classes your source .

[Please refer to this basic tutorial , article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/MySQLJava/article.html)

Comment: Already added the mysql *.jar to my classpath. Am I missing something inside the code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have jar file to connect database. You can download `mysql-connector-java-3.1.12.jar`.

Please, download it and place it in the `lib` folder of your web application. This should fix your problem.

If you have any other problem, you can refer this tutorial for [steps to connect MySQL using JDBC](http://www.apekshit.com/t/51/Steps-to-connect-Database-using-JAVA)