# How to Connect Online hosted my sql database using java coding?

Tags: java, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect Java to Mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385392/how-to-connect-java-to-mysql)

I have a website and its my MySQL database in blue-host.I also have in-house warehouse software in Java.
I want to connect from my in house desktop software with on-line hosted my MySQL server.
Can any one tell me how to connect?

Answer (score 2):

You probably can't: Most providers don't allow external access to their databases.

Ask your provider; they will also be able to provide you with all necessary data if it's possible after all.

Comment: IF they grant access then how I will connect in Java?

Comment: @saddam just like you connect to any other mySQL database, I suppose? I don't know, I don't do Java.

Answer (score 0):

After you have got the connection parameters from your provider (if they do that at all),you can look at the MySQL documentation itself, how to connect to the database:

- JDBC Connector main: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j.html
- Connection examples: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-examples.html