# Can anyone say how to connect a java project to a XAMP database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, xampp

Hi I need to know how I can do the database connection on a java project in Netbeans. I am creating my database through xamp. Do I have to add the database to some location of my project. And what is the code segment used for connecting?

Comment: you mean mysql database?

Comment: @th1rdey3 yes. for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Read the following thread and try the MySQL J Connector:

MySQL J Connector:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

How to connect Java to MySQL:
[How to connect Java to Mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385392/how-to-connect-java-to-mysql)